# How to route between two private network?

Tags: ip, router, vpn, ethernet

I know that routers will drop ip packets with private destination ip.Then how to route between private networks?
If there is no solution to that,then how do private networks in a big corporation communicate with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> routers will drop ip packets with private destination ip

No. Only when they are configured that way - usually when they route into a public IP range area. Consumer routers may be preconfigured that way in their firmware.

> how to route between private networks?

Set up the router with a working routing table and let it do its job.

Routing private destination IP addresses across public IP networks involves tunneling, most often encrypted tunneling (VPN). The local tunnel gateway wraps the actual IP packet in a transport packet that's addressed to the remote gateway. The transport packet is routed normally and on arrival at the remote gateway, the wrapper is removed and the actual packet restored.